# how to change focus from one part of screen to other on a button click in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have an activity divided in two parts - ***first part*** containing 4 buttons and corresponding to those buttons i have 4 fragments such that, when i click on Button-1 , fragment-1 is shown in ***second part*** of the screen below the 4 buttons and when i click on button-2, fragment-2 is shown in second part of the screen. So, i want that on clicking a button , its corresponding fragment should come in focus otherwise the user due to long layout length will not be able to know that there is some content available below which he can visit on using scroll?

I have attached an image about how my app works presently.[image]

*I have a scroll in the activity but want the fragment to expand a bit on screen sliding the buttons upward on its own on a button click.*

I tried searching it over internet but couldn't find anything relevant!

Please provide code help!!!

Comment: Basically you want to scroll the `scrollView` programmatically.

Comment: Do u want the whole layout should scrollable Or only content should scrollable??

Comment: You can use Object Animator's translateY animation  for sliding the fragment.

Comment: Guys! I want that when i click on any chip icon then the corresponding fragment that can be seen below should automatically slide upward to make it easier for the user to read.